# Start neo4j-community.exe server automatically & load the database?

Tags: neo4j

On windows, is there a way to run `neo4j-community.exe` with either a command-line options or with a setting file so that it starts the server and loads the database automatially instead of having it to "start" manually after launching it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the "Zip-Download" you can also install Neo4j as a service:

```
Usage - Windows

To just control the Neo4j Server, use the Neo4j.bat command.

Neo4jInstaller.bat install/remove

Neo4j can be installed and run as a Windows Service, running without
a console window. You’ll need to run the scripts with Administrator
privileges. Just use the Neo4jInstaller.bat script with the proper
argument
```